# Trying to resolve problem in Python 1-D Partial Differential Equation solver

Tags: python, github, typeerror, pde

I am trying to write and modify a function from the following github account to generate a solution for 1-D partial differential equation (PDE)  that uses the " solver_FE_simple " definition listed close to the top.

https://github.com/hplgit/fdm-book/blob/master/src/diffu/diffu1D_u0.py

After I specify inputs and run the code I am given an error output that fits the following structure.

u_n[i] = I(x[i])

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable.

I was hoping you could provide some guidance on how to further modify in order to overcome this error. Best regards.

```
Nx=100 #The total number of mesh cells; mesh points are numbered from 0 to Nx.
a=1E-6
dt=0.1#Constant mesh spacing in t.
dx=0.1 #Constant mesh spacing in x.
F=a*dt/dx**2 #F     The dimensionless number a*dt/dx**2, which implicitly 
specifies the time step.
T=100 #The stop time for the simulation.
I=1 #Initial Condition, Python Function of x
L=50 # Length of the domain ([0,L]).
x=500 #Mesh points in space.
t=300 #Mesh points in time.
n=2   #Index counter in time.
f=1 



import time
import numpy as np

def solver_FE_simple(I, a, f, L, dt, F, T):
t0 = time.process_time()  # For measuring the CPU time

Nt = int(round(T/float(dt)))
t = np.linspace(0, Nt*dt, Nt+1)   # Mesh points in time
dx = np.sqrt(a*dt/F)
Nx = int(round(L/dx))
print(Nx)
x = np.linspace(0, L, Nx+1)       # Mesh points in space
# Make sure dx and dt are compatible with x and t
dx = x[1] - x[0]
dt = t[1] - t[0]

u   = np.zeros(Nx+1)
u_n = np.zeros(Nx+1)

# Set initial condition u(x,0) = I(x)
for i in range(0, Nx+1):
    u_n[i] = I(x[i])

for n in range(0, Nt):
    # Compute u at inner mesh points
    for i in range(1, Nx):
        u[i] = u_n[i] + F*(u_n[i-1] - 2*u_n[i] + u_n[i+1]) + \
               dt*f(x[i], t[n])

    # Insert boundary conditions
    u[0] = 0;  u[Nx] = 0

    # Switch variables before next step
    #u_n[:] = u  # safe, but slow
    u_n[:]= u

t1 = time.process_time()
return u_n, x, t, t1-t0  # u_n holds latest u
print(solver_FE_simple(I, a, f, L, dt, F, T))
```

runfile('C:/Users/PC/OneDrive/Desktop/ProgramsFrom2020/Modelz/modeltest3.py', wdir='C:/Users/PC/OneDrive/Desktop/ProgramsFrom2020/Modelz')
500
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    runfile('C:/Users/PC/OneDrive/Desktop/ProgramsFrom2020/Modelz/modeltest3.py', wdir='C:/Users/PC/OneDrive/Desktop/ProgramsFrom2020/Modelz')

File "C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/PC/OneDrive/Desktop/ProgramsFrom2020/Modelz/modeltest3.py", line 102, in 
    solver_FE_simple(I, a, f, L, dt, F, T)

File "C:/Users/PC/OneDrive/Desktop/ProgramsFrom2020/Modelz/modeltest3.py", line 85, in solver_FE_simple
    u_n[i] = I(x[i])

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: Would you mind printing the entire stack trace? In particular, on what line does the error occur?

Comment: stack trace updated. thanks for any help you might be able to provide!

Comment: You defined `I=1` at the beginning. So what do you expect `I(x[i])` would be ? Shouldn't `I()` be defined as a function instead.